# BeforeInsertAnchorable never invoke (Avalon Dock 3.2.0.0)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I tried to add anchorables to specific destinition. In order to do that i tried to implement ILayoutUpdateStrategy:

```
public class DockingContentInitializer : ILayoutUpdateStrategy
{
    public void AfterInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableShown)
    {

    }

    public void AfterInsertDocument(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutDocument anchorableShown)
    {

    }

    public bool BeforeInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableToShow, ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
    {
        LayoutAnchorablePane _Destination = destinationContainer as LayoutAnchorablePane;
        if (destinationContainer != null &&destinationContainer.FindParent<LayoutFloatingWindow>() != null)
            return false;
        if(anchorableToShow.Content is IMainAnchorContent)
        { 
            if(layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "MainPane") == null)
            {
                LayoutAnchorablePane MainPane = new LayoutAnchorablePane();
                MainPane.Name = "MainPane";
                layout.RootPanel.Children.Insert(0, MainPane);
                MainPane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                (layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "MainPane") as LayoutAnchorablePane).Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
                return true;
            }

        }
        if (anchorableToShow.Content is IAdditionalAnchorContent)
        {
            if (layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "AdditionPane") == null)
            {
                LayoutAnchorablePane Pane = new LayoutAnchorablePane();
                Pane.Name = "AdditionPane";
                layout.RootPanel.Children.Add(Pane);
                Pane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                (layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "AdditionPane") as LayoutAnchorablePane).Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool BeforeInsertDocument(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutDocument anchorableToShow, ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

MainView.xaml

```
 <avalon:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" 
                           Grid.Row="2" 
                           BorderBrush="Black"
                           Margin="3"
                           Background="#FFFDFDFD"
                           BorderThickness="0"
                           DataContext="{Binding DockingManager}"
                           DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                           AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}">

        <avalon:DockingManager.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProjectTreeViewModel}">
                <local:ProjectTreeView  />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ComponentTreeViewModel}">
                <local:ComponentTreeView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </avalon:DockingManager.Resources>`<avalon:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
            <behaviors:DockingContentInitializer />
        </avalon:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
        <avalon:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonctrl:LayoutItem}">
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseTabCommand}"/>
                <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanCloseTab}"/>
            </Style>
        </avalon:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    </avalon:DockingManager>`
```

My view-model adding correctly, but BeforeInsertAnchorable method never invoked and thats lead to view-models placed to default AnchorablePane on the right.
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i figure it out - i used MVVM Light that initialised viewModel with anchorables collection before loading view with DockingManager. Thats leads to creation of two layout's in RootPanel instead of one and looks like that cause the problem.

Now, i wait before DockingManager "Loaded" and only then put elements into my Anchorable collection.

Comment: Thanks, your question and answer helped me figure out what was wrong in my situation.